# Copy DataTable to DataTable keeping the PrimaryKey

Tags: datatable, copy, primary-key

1. I need to copy `dt2` into `dt1` but I can't use `dt1 = dt2` because `dt1` has a primary key while `dt2` does not. What's the best way to do this?
2. Is is possible to add a primary key to an existing dataTable which is not empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just searching for how to set primary key - found solution:

```
dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["ColumnName"] };
```

I needed this for merging datatables, so it might help to copy one into an other.